# UIView disappear after wrapped into a stack view

Tags: ios, uiview, uistackview

The view hierarchy is simple:

```
Scroll view (UIScrollView)
    - Content View (UIView)
      - Stack View
         - Hello (UILabel)
         - White view (UIView)
```

As shown below:

[image]

As you see above, the Stack View consists of only two components the Hello (UILabel) and White view (UIView).

What I am encountering is, if I **don't** embed these two components into a Stack View, running it on device **I can see both** the "Hello" UIlabel and the white view.

**BUT, After I embedded them inside a vertical Stack View,** I can only see the "Hello" (UILabel), the white UIView disappear, no matter what constraints I added or removed, no matter how I adjust stack view attribute, it just doesn't show, I always end up with following on device (though everything shows fine on storyboard):

[image]

Why?

**=== more info ===**

In [View Hierarchy Debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html) of xcode I see Scroll View-->Content View--> Stack View--> the UILabel, I don't see the white view. I don't understand why

Comment: Have you set the white view‘s height?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth, No I didn't, but I use a constraint that makes the white view height equal to the parent view's height, then changed the multiplier to 0.8, in this way the white view height will be proportional to its parent on different devices. I don't want to set constant height, because I want the height to be proportional.

Comment: Ah I see. What does it show you when debugging the view hierarchy at runtime? Can you see the white view?

Comment: At runtime, I see what I attached the screenshot, I only see the Hello UILabel. But in xcode where I can choose different device screens, it shows fine without issue. Issue comes at runtime in emulator and real device.

Comment: I was asking what do you see when you [debug the view hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth, in view hierarchy debugger, I see Scroll View-->Content View--> Stack View--> the UILabel, I don't see the white view. I don't understand why the white uiview disappear also in hierarchy debugger.

Comment: Put `print(whiteView)` somewhere. What does it say?

Comment: is the `whiteView` tag name of the view? I mean what is `whiteView` variable? Where should I add it so that xcode knows it refers to the "White View" UIView? (I will be back in 15min)

Comment: Oh well you need to create a reference to it first. I assumed you’d already done that. (I’ll be back in 8 - hours though, ha, see ya)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth, the `print(whiteView)` prints out `Optional(<UIView: 0x7f85f970f1d0; frame = (0 87; 375 301); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x60800002a1e0>>)`

Comment: Actually, in view hierarchy debugger, it shows the white view, but it doesn't show on the graphic view when I rotate the view stack, I don't see the white view.